# Python-2.7 zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option '/' not supported)

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell

I'm reading *A Byte of Python*，which contains something about how to write a script to zip a file. I have checked my code for several times and still can't find where the bug lies. I want to know what's wrong with my code.BTW,I'm using Mac,thanks.

```
import os
import time
source=[r'/Users/username/Desktop/test.txt']
target_dir=r'/Users/username/Desktop/backup'
target=target_dir+time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')+'.zip'
print target
zip_command="zip -qr'%s'%s"%(target,''.join(source))
if os.system(zip_command)==0:
    print 'successful backup to',target
else:
    print 'backup failed'
```

- zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option '/' not supported)
  backup failed

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're missing some spaces in your command format string. Try `"zip -qr '%s' %s"`. You probably also want to be `join`ing the `source` items with a space between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing spaces in your `zip` arguments. The error you see is caused by you path being interpreted as a list of options because you have:

```
zip -qr/Users/username/Desktop/test.txt
```

...instead of:

```
zip -qr /Users/username/Desktop/test.txt
```

Replace this line:

```
zip_command="zip -qr'%s'%s"%(target,''.join(source))
```

...by this:

```
zip_command="zip -qr '%s' %s"%(target,''.join(source))
```